# How can I include Dresden-Files-style vampires in my Pathfinder game?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters, dresden-files

I have a concept for a campaign that uses a Dresden-Files environment in a medieval fantasy setting, but for reasons of familiarity and experience prefer to use the Pathfinder system. I specifically need to be able to create stat-blocks for the vampires. I'm not sure I understand the vampire system well enough to create them myself. I understand there is a Dresden-Files RPG, and I don't know of any conversion techniques for Dresden stat block -> Pathfinder stat block. My player characters are built according to standard Pathfinder rules, it's only the monster blocks that need creating.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Dresden Files is a different paradigm in RPGs than Pathfinder.  The concept of statistics doesn't enter into the picture.  What you would probably want to do is to take a vampire in Pathfinder, then take the spirit of the Vampires of the Courts in Dresden.

Black Court Vampires (OW85) would do very well as [standard Pathfinder vampires](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/vampire); from the Dresden Files, these are the standard vampire that we usually think of.

Red Court Vampires (OW88) would be similar; I'd keep the Energy Drain, Blood Drain, Create Spawn, and Change Shape (but only to a Dire Bat) abilities, and the weakness to Sunlight and Holy Things, but remove the other special attacks and qualities.  In place of those, the addictive saliva (which would be a variant on dominate), and the vulnerability in the stomach would have to be modeled.

@JonathanHobbs suggested in the comments that a slightly increased critical range might be good for modeling the vulnerability in the stomach.  I like that approach, though @CRoss suggested a reduction in the natural armor that vampires receive.

White Court Vampires (OW90) would be a bit more tricky.  Keep Energy Drain, and feeding would have to be altered to be based on that.  All other special attacks and qualities are invalid- other than a variant on Dominate to emulate the incite emotion.  Their Energy Drain would be dependent on the victim being under that effect.  Their only drawback would be the vulnerability to emotion.

For the Raiths, for an example, I'd probably use [Charm Person](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/charm-person) and/or [Enthrall](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/enthrall), one to represent the attention of the Vampire on one target; the other one their ability to affect a crowd by their presence.  [Honeyed Tongue](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/honeyed-tongue) might also be appropriate, as the more subtle effect probably better represents their influence.

There are other tweaks- but they won't be direct conversions; the systems just don't lend themselves to that IMO.  Just keep the spirit of the vampire, while modeling off of the pathfinder version.

Comment: What if I'd like different "ages" of vampire? Should that just be NPC levels on top of whatever template we can create?

Comment: You could make certain abilities only available to vampires after aging, or you could just say that as they get older, they get more experienced- or a combination of the two.  That would be by preference.

Comment: I'd recommend adding NPC levels.  The powers of older Dresden vampires are depicted as being quite variable and individual... The Red King's an evil priest, Mavra's a wizard, Lara's a warrior / noble, and most tellingly, Ortega's a warrior but his wife's a wizard.

Comment: Since the Black Court is the Bram Stoker vampire and in Pathfinder that's the [Nosferatu](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/nosferatu), perhaps that would be a better equivalence than the standard PF vampire?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie - It could, as a matter of choice be used- I guess what sways me that you're possibly right is the fact that they are a dying breed, as is the Black Court.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, Black Court are pretty close to the standard vampire.

Red Court need blood to get powerful but you can kill them by puncturing their stomachs to spill their blood, so maybe give them a bonus after feeding or a bonus that's based on their current HP?

White Courts are meant to play on the succubus myths more than the vampire myths, so you might use a succubus with the spell-like abilities and shapeshifting trimmed off.